# Component identification needed (marking: fPAUBP V595)

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

[image]

Can you help identify this 16-pin IC? There are several of them, and on the other side there are many LEDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairchild 74VHC595MTC, which means in 16-pin TSSOP package.